# Remove first element in Deque (Python) is O(1)?

Tags: python, deque

I wanna pop out the first (or the nth) element of a list (or deque). My friend told me the deque structure is O(1) operation. I am not talkign about poping out the last element. I am talking about poping out the first or the nth element.

Comment: Deques (double-ended queues) are O(1) for popping from either end, and O(n) for removing from the middle.

Comment: Deque insert on either side is O(1).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, removing this first element or the last (as well as inserting) is `O(1)`

You can see more information about that [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), quoting from there:

> The complexity (efficiency) of common operations on deques is as
> follows:
>
> - Random access - constant O(1)
> - Insertion or removal of elements at the end or beginning - constant O(1)
> - Insertion or removal of elements - linear O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Poping out the first element is O(1). But poping out the nth element is probably not.

As written in the python documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects

> Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction.

It is possible to build a data structure that can pop out nth element in constant time, but the space complexity will not be satisfactory.